# Using get_terms() as shortcode attribute

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, shortcode, terms, customization

Hop you pepople would be fine. I'm creating a shortcode with the following code.

```
$categories = get_terms( 'project-type' );

foreach ($categories as $category) {

    $portfolio_terms[$category->slug] = $category->name;

}

$ABdevDND_shortcodes['portfolio_DD'] = array(
    'attributes' => array(
        'category' => array(
            'default' => 'all',
            'type' => 'select',
            'values' => $portfolio_terms,
            'description' => __('Category', 'dnd-shortcodes'),
        ),      
        'style' => array(
            'default' => 'classic_gallery',
            'type' => 'select',
            'values' => array( 
                'classic_gallery' => 'Classic Style',
                'alternative_gallery' => 'Alternative Style',
            ),
            'description' => __('Style', 'dnd-shortcodes'),
        ),

    ),
    'description' => __('Portfolio', 'dnd-shortcodes' )
);
function ABdevDND_portfolio_DD_shortcode( $attributes, $content = null ) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(ABdevDND_extract_attributes('portfolio_DD'), $attributes));

    ob_start();  
    get_template_part( 'lib/blocks/portfolio', 'index' );  
    $return = ob_get_contents();  
    ob_end_clean();  
    return $return;


}
```

shortcode is working just fine, but the only issue is i'm unable to populate taxonomy array values from $portfolio_terms variable. It outputs nothing.

The question is, how i populate category attribute with all avaiable terms of 'project-type' with slug as key and name as value?

Comment: Missing some code. For example, `ABdevDND_extract_attributes`? This looks like mostly a PHP problem right now though.

Comment: Solved the issue! This code is in plugin and taxonomy is being registered in theme files. Plugin files are loaded before theme files that why get_terms() returns nothing.

Comment: And that is why some things are best in plugins rather than themes.